# Why $ \sum _{k=0} ^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{k} x^{k+1} = \sum _{k=1} ^{n} \binom{n-1}{k-1} x^k $?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, arithmetic, integers

I'm struggling to understand how to get from this:
$$ \sum _{k=0} ^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{k} x^{k+1}  $$
to this:
$$ \sum _{k=1} ^{n} \binom{n-1}{k-1} x^k  $$
I always have a problem understand the shifting of limits in general. Does there exist a guide/book somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following representation might also be helpful. We can write
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k}&=\sum_{\color{blue}{0\leq k\leq n-1}}\binom{n-1}{k}\tag{1}\\
&=\sum_{\color{blue}{1\leq k\leq n}}\binom{n-1}{k-1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n-1}{k-1}\tag{2}
\end{align*}

**Some aspects:**

- In (1) we use another common notation for the index region $0\leq k\leq n-1$. Here $k$ is the *index* variable going from $0$ to $n-1$.
- In (2) we shift the index variable by adding $1$ so that the index region becomes $1\leq k\leq n$. But we don't want to change the sum. We so have to *compensate* this by *subtracting* $1$ at each occurrence of $k$.
- This technique is independent from binomial coefficients. We have
  \begin{align*}
    \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_k&=\sum_{\color{blue}{0\leq k\leq n-1}}a_k\\
    &=a_0+a_1+\cdots+a_{n-1}\\
    &=\sum_{\color{blue}{1\leq k\leq n}}a_{k-1}=\sum_{k=1}^na_{k-1}
  \end{align*}

**Hint:** A thorough introduction in working with sums is given in chapter 2: *Sums* in *[Concrete Mathematics](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Er97002/temp/Concrete%20Mathematics%202e.pdf)* by R. L. Graham, D. Knuth and O. Patashnik.

Comment: That’s super helpful. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @DuncanTaylor: You're welcome! :-)

Answer (score 7):

You should use a different variable name, here:

$$k':=k+1 \iff k=k'-1$$

In this way:

$$\sum _{k=0} ^{k=n-1} \binom{n-1}{k} x^{k+1}\tag{1}$$

(where I have cautiously written $k=...$ for the initial **and** the final values.)

becomes

$$\sum _{k'-1=0} ^{k'-1=n-1} \binom{n-1}{k'-1} x^{k'-1+1}$$

Otherwise said:

$$\sum _{k'=1} ^{k'=n} \binom{n-1}{k'-1} x^{k'}$$

Now, you are free to rename $k'$ as $k$...

Comment: That’s great. Thanks so much.

Comment: @DuncanTaylor So you can mark the answer as accepted.